# Варьирующиеся параметры для каждого элемента при применении lapply

Tags: r, cluster

Я делаю кластерный анализ с помощью k-means. У меня сгенерировано 720 датасетов сгруппированных в один лист и есть отдельный датасет содержащий значения числа центров (`k`) для каждого из 720 датасетов. Я пытаюсь сделать так чтобы кластерный анализ был выполнен сразу для всех датасетов в листе в одно действие с помощью `lapply` и было выбрано соответствующее каждому датасету число центров. Проблема в том что я не знаю как сделать так чтобы `lapply` помимо чередования датасетов, чередовал соответствующие им числа центров.

Пример:

```
# генерируем 5 датасетов
set.seed(199)
df1<-data.frame(replicate(4,sample(1:100,40,rep=TRUE)))
df2<-data.frame(replicate(3,sample(1:100,30,rep=TRUE)))
df3<-data.frame(replicate(5,sample(1:100,20,rep=TRUE)))
df4<-data.frame(replicate(6,sample(1:100,40,rep=TRUE)))
df5<-data.frame(replicate(3,sample(1:100,50,rep=TRUE)))

# засовываем их в лист
list_df = list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
list_names = c("df1", "df2", "df3", "df4", "df5")
list_df<-setNames(list_df, list_names)

# создаем датасет с центрами для каждого датасета
df_centers <- data.frame(centers=c(3,4,2,6,8))

# попытка применить lapply (код неверный)
km.clust <- lapply(list_df, kmeans, centers = df_centers$centers)
```

Я пытаюсь сделать это подобным образом, однако я не знаю как сделать так чтобы `kmeans` использовал соответствующие центры из `df_centers` для каждого датасета в листе `list_df`. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вы уже сами поняли, `mapply()` является наиболее подходящим вариантом. Но можно также использовать и `lapply()`, просто вместо значений нужно передать индексы:

```
km.clust <- lapply(seq_along(list_df), function(i) {
    kmeans(list_df[[i]], centers = df_centers$centers[i])
})
```

Также не стоит забывать про `parallel::mcmapply`, которая является аналогом функции `mapply` с поддержкой параллелизации (можно значитльено ускорить код при работе с большим количество датасетов).

Если нужно варьировать большое количество параметров, то удобно использовать функцию `pmap` из пакета `purrr`:

```
params <- list(x = list_df, centers = df_centers$centers)
km.clust <- purrr::pmap(params, kmeans)
```

Answer (score 2):

Решил вопрос сам. Замена lapply на mapply позволяет использовать варьирующиеся параметры для каждого элемента.

```
km.clust <- mapply(kmeans, list_df, centers = df_centers$centers)
```

Comment: В вызов `mapply()` лучше добавить `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`, т.к. `kmeans` возвращает список.